# How to declare proptypes to validate an array of specific strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A value passed to component can be an array of strings. That strings means different directions: `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`.

How to specify proptypes for component to allow only array of specified directions?

```
  <Arrows
    directions=['left', 'bottom'] // accepts the array
  />
```

```
  <Arrows
   directions=['left', 'back'] // doesn't accept the array
  />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
directions: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOf(['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'])),
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of [PropTypes](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types) for the Runtime type checking for React props.

Using the `PropTypes.arrayOf()` option to ensure that an array of specific values are passed. And as an argument, you pass `PropTypes.oneOf()` which accepts an array of values (the directions of the **Arrow**) to select from.

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Arrow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // ... do things with the props
  }
}

Arrow.propTypes = {
   directions: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOf(['left', 'bottom']))
}
```